# Problem using Add View dialog in ASP.NET MVC RC1 for strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I like the new Add View dialog that was released with RC1.  If you specify a view data class, it generates a scaffolded view for you.  It seems to work fine with classes defined in projects within my solution.  Some of my domain classes inherit from a base class that is defined in an external assembly (and referenced in my web project).  I get an error when I specify one of these domain classes.  Visual Studio is reporting a TypeLoadException on the external base class.

I did a little debugging with ProcMon and found that it was looking for the base class DLL in, among other places, a temporary folder.  That folder did contain the DLL containing my derived domain model class.  I did not see the base class's DLL.  So for fun, I copied it there and voila, I could add the view.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Same here. Will u pls post the work-around here?

Comment: The work around I found was to put the external assembly in the temporary folder that ASP.NET is using while processing the dialog box.  The way I found the temporary folder was to run the SysInternals Procmon utility to display the folders that are searched to find the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a bug.  Please file it on http://codeplex.com/aspnet

Comment: Thanks.  I see it has already been reported.  Thanks.  I was going to post my work-around, but I'm having problems logging in.

Answer (score 0):

you actually forgot to add the Web.Config file on the View Folder.
See this small article : http://www.graytechnology.com/Blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-strongly-typed-view-error-Could-not-load-type.aspx

It got me scratching my head quite a bit as well in my current project! :)