# Asp.net MVC 3 code generation fails with n-tier application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-generation, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to generate strongly typed Views based on models outside of my mvc project (in the business layer project), I get no code generation for the View. So for example my details page doesn't automatically generate the table to display the detail of the model passed to it. This is not the case when the models are directly inside of my MVC project. Is it possible to have an n-tier application and still get this code generation for strongly typed views?

EDIT: Answer-

Add a line for your namespace of the business layer into the web.config of the views folder like so

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
     <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="<My business layer namespace>" />
     </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Then code generation will work when you create a strongly typed view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try custom ViewModels or importing the namespace into the page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your.Namespace.Here" %>
```

It also looks like [you may need to add the assembly information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492671/problem-using-add-view-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc-rc1-for-strongly-typed-view) to the `web.config` that's located in your `Views` folder.

Comment: I'm confused about how what your saying would help with the code generation. I'm referring to creating a new View > selecting strongly typed view > selecting a model for the view that is in the business layer project. When it's created the automatic generation of the asp tags to pull the model information out into a table are not made. That's one of the biggest benefits to mvc imho. So without that how are you supposed to build an n-tier application effectively?

Comment: I'm just so confused about why they have the code generation if you can't have a business layer and still get that to happen. How is someone supposed to build an enterprise n-tier application if you have to put your BL inside your models?

Comment: @Matt Phillips you don't have to put your BL Inside your models, but you do need to reference the namespace in the view web.config appropriately.

Comment: @Matt I'm glad your issue was solved. Sometimes the Microsoft stack can be a pain.